# Capturing the windows key in c# (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

I have written a small program displaying sounds and images on the screen when pushing any button.  I always start it when one of my little kids crawls onto my lap and start hitting the keys, of course, randomly.

It works fine except for 2 keys, one of them being the ON/OFF switch, the other being the Windows-key. (the CTRL-ESC equivalent I believe)  I can intercept it as it is pressed, but only after the startmenu is showing.

The event I use is the UIElement.KeyDown and all I could came up with so far is :  (the e being KeyEventArgs)

```
            if (e.Key == Key.LWin) e.Handled = true;
```

but than the start window is already showing I'm afraid.

I have already 1 answer but would very much like to know if there's any wpf-support?

I suspect programming the main on/off switch might not be possible?  Otherwise, any help there would be welcome too..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need a [keyboard hook](https://github.com/shanselman/babysmash/blob/master/KeyboardHook.cs). Unfortunately, this has to be done with P/Invoke; it can't be done with managed code.

Check out [Baby Smash!](http://www.babysmash.com) by Scott Hanselman. It's hosted on <s>code plex at http://www.codeplex.com/babysmash</s> Github at https://github.com/shanselman/babysmash

Alternatively, check out [ShapeShow](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ShapeShow.aspx) on CodeProject, which is similar.

Comment: That's definitely an answer, tx.  But it requires interop, no native wpf support you're aware of?

Comment: Yep. Needs interop. Updated AB's answer to explain that, and added link to ShapeShow.

Comment: Ok, If you guys are sure, thanks for answering! (I alreaydy have installed babysmash in the meantime)

Comment: Note: the answer by merrick (below) works perfectly. Though I'm not sure if that API was already available when this answer was written. (Just adding this here as I completely missed that answer the first time I read this page).

Comment: e.Key == Key.LWin is all you need.  See answer by merrick

Answer (score 4):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key(v=VS.90).aspx

At the bottom you'll see a simple example, I think what you're looking for is something along these lines:

left windows key: System.Windows.Input.Key.LWin

right windows key: System.Windows.Input.Key.RWin

example:

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LWin) {
        textBlock1.Text = "You Entered: " + textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```