# Replacing and creating windows shortcuts

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, winapi

I want to implement in my application a code for the app to react when the user presses <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. Then how can I create a shortcut to work with the Windows key?
(I want to learn how to replace the default Windows shortcut keys - the ones with <kbd>Windows</kbd>)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: It seems much harder than one would at first assume. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/767528/976080)

Comment: @SidHolland I think this is a lot more complicated than I need it I want just to create shortcut keys in my application that include  WinLogo key

Answer (score 2):

Actually keys like the Windows key doesn't have an ASCII value.

Complete answer [here](http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=76247)and [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-i-change-the-windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts/0110d32d-66c0-4ce7-8682-eeb896e80c3f)

Comment: You're missing your second link.