# Keyboard.Modifiers is None when pressing the Windows modifier key

Tags: c#, wpf, key-bindings

The Surface Pen sends the signal WindowsKey+F20/19 whenever the button on the back is clicked or double clicked and I would like to capture this in my application.

I've seen [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767513/capturing-the-windows-key-in-c-sharp-wpf) about detecting when the Windows Key is pressed and it seems this is not possible in C# without PInvoke.

However, I'm not sure if this also applies to the Windows Key as a modifier. It seems so, but I'd like to know for sure.

The [ModifierKeys enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.modifierkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation lists the Windows Key and there seem to be no special remarks regarding this key.

So I've wired up the main window's OnPreviewKeyDown even to this code:

```
private void MainWindow_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SystemKey == Key.F10 &&
         e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers.HasFlag(System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Windows)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Succes!");
    }
}
```

This code works if I listen to the alt modifier key, however if I press `Windows+F10` `e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers` equals `None` and thus the if condition fails.

Is there anything I'm missing or should I go the PInvoke route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should be able to detect `Windows+F10`:

```
private void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SystemKey == Key.F10 && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LWin) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RWin)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Succes!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. Because I read multiple accounts that you need PInvoke I disregarded that answer in the question I linked. My bad :).

Comment: ofc, I had to wait one more minute before I could :)