# Detect Shift + LWin + Left key combination in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

On a windows form, how can I detect the combination of keys Shift + LWin + Left?

I tried the following on a form (with KeyPreview = true) without success.

```
    private void frmPlaceholderRectangle_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift && (e.KeyCode == (Keys.Left | Keys.LWin)))
        {
            //Do Something
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing the windows key in c# (wpf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767513/capturing-the-windows-key-in-c-sharp-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary workaround that will suffice:

```
    private bool _ShiftWin = false;

    private void frmPlaceholderRectangle_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.LWin)
        {
            _ShiftWin = true;
            txtShowName.Text = "Shift+Win Down at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void frmPlaceholderRectangle_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_ShiftWin && e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            txtShowName.Text = "Left Key Up at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
        if (_ShiftWin && e.KeyCode == Keys.LWin)
        {
            txtShowName.Text = "Shift+Win Up at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            _ShiftWin = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That looks like it will only work if Shift + LWin are pressed before Left, correct? Do you care about the order of keys?

Comment: Since Shift & LWin are being used as modifiers, they must be pressed first, otherwise it is a different keystroke (e.g. either shift+Left or LWin+Left).

Comment: @"Rufus L" - Yes, I am trying to react to my window being moved by the Shift+LWin+Left sequence, which requires the Shift+LWin to be put down first and held while the Left is added. In this case, the window moves and when the user lets go of the Left key, the code fires the part I want.